# fwrite file output is wrong

Tags: c, file, binary, endianness

I am trying to write a binary representation of the integer into a file , accepted that I will get hexadecimal format in the file, however I don't get the expected result.

```
uint32_t a = 1;
FILE * file = fopen("out.txt", "ab+");
fwrite(&a, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, file );
```

I expect to get (little endian)

```
1000 0000
```

but instead I get in the file

```
0100 0000
```

The machine running this snippet of code is Ubuntu linux 32 bit (little endian).
Is there someone who could explain why it's like so , is the file's content consistent with the integer representation on my machine ? 
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each of those groups of two digits is a byte, what you're seeing is correct:

```
01 00 00 00
```

Little endian orders *bytes,* not nybbles *within* bytes. So what you have is:

```
01 00 00 00
|| || || ||
|| || || == -> 0 * 256 * 256 * 256
|| || == ----> 0 * 256 * 256
|| == -------> 0 * 256
== ----------> 1
```